# Open Module Settings window not opening in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android studio not opening the **Module settings** window. i tried to open the **Project Structure**.but not opening that window also. My android studio version is 1.5.1.i used the shortcut key F4 and restarted the android studio also. but no use. kindly help me how can i open the module settings.
when i try to open Module settings window i got Error: **IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: 
Google Inc.:Google APIs:19=Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 19) and Google Inc.:Google APIs:19=Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 19)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall Api Leavel 19 and reinstall.this works for me